# What are the towers for in DW7?

Tags: dynasty-warriors-7

In Dynasty Warriors 7, there are various guard towers on some maps that you can climb up. What are they for? You no longer have arrows that I can tell (like DW5:E), so what's the point of being able to go up there?

Can you still knock them down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the guard towers in certain missions are actually Signal Towers, which have to be destroyed to prevent the enemy from revealing your sneak attack. Other than that, they don't seem to have a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think they serve much of a purpose beyond decoration.

I think archer units use them to attack from occasionally. (I've climbed them and killed enemies on top, but am not really sure if they actually attack from up there)

I think you can knock them down.